# Gettign Error : Image source not readable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-resizing, laravel-5.8

I have successfully uploaded image. But getting below error while trying to resize before upload an image.

> Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
>   Image source not readable

**Controller.php**

```
        $image=$request->product_image; 
        $thumbnailSize = '150X150';

        $upload_path='image/product/'.$request->product_name.'/';           

        $imageName = $request->product_name.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $thumbnailImageName = $request->product_name.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension().$thumbnailSize;

        $image_url = $upload_path.$imageName;

        $thumbnail_image_url = $upload_path.$thumbnailImageName;

        $image->move(storage_path($upload_path), $imageName);

        $resize_image = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

        $resize_image->resize(150, 150, function($constraint){
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($upload_path);
```

I have also updated my composer with `"intervention/image": "dev-master"` in `config/app.php`

Anybody Help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$upload_path = storage_path().'image/product/'.$request->product_name.'/'; 

$image=$request->product_image; 
$imageName = $request->product_name.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image->move($upload_path, $imageName);

$thumbnailSize = '150X150';
$thumbnailImageName = $thumbnailSize.$imageName;
File::copy($upload_path . $imageName, $upload_path . $thumbnailImageName);
Image::make($upload_path . $thumbnailImageName)
->resize(150, 150, function($constraint){
$constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($upload_path . $thumbnailImageName);
```

Add this in top

```
use Image;
use File;
```

hope this will help!

Comment: new error shown `Encoding format (jpg150X150) is not supported.`

Comment: @ArafatRahman In the code above,  `$thumbnailImageName` name has the wrong file extension and while Intervention is trying to encode the image it is finding "jpg150X150" as an extension. Fix it and the encoding error should go or encode manually using `encode()` method